# An exemple of compact operador set that isnt closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to found an exemple of set $K(E,F)=\{T:E\to F, \text{linear and compact}\}$ that is not closed... I know that F cant be Banach, then i tried st like $F=\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ and $E=\mathbb{R}$ and constructed a sequence of compact linear operator  that the limit cant be a compact operator, but i dont know how to do this. Some ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $E=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $F\subset E$ the subspace of sequences with only finitely many nonzero elements. Now consider the operators $T_n:E\to F$ given by 
$$
T_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(a_1,\frac{a_2}2,\frac{a_3}3,\ldots).
$$
The sequence $\{T_n\}$ is Cauchy (because $\|T_n-T_m\|\leq\max\{\frac1n,\frac1m\}$), but the limit doesn't exist in $K(E,F)$.

Comment: when do you write $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, is this the set of sequences that each a_n is natural? is this a normed space?

Comment: No, if that were the case, my definition of $T_n$ would make no sense. It's a [fairly common notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#General_%E2%84%93p-space) that emphasizes what index set is used.